# Count List of Objects inside JSONField in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class TopCountries(models.Model):
    top_countries = JSONField(null=True)
```

**top_countries** is JSONField

```
'top_countries': [
  {'country_code': 'AX', 'country_name': 'Åland Islands'},
  {'country_code': 'AL', 'country_name': 'Albania'},
  {'country_code': 'DZ', 'country_name': 'Algeria'}
 ]
```

I am new to advanced queries. I've tried the query below but it does not give me the desired output.

Query:

```
TopCountries.objects.aggregate(Count('top_countries'))
```

Output:

```
{'top_countries__count': 1}
```

Desired Output:

```
{'top_countries__count': 3}
```

Comment: Can you please add your `UserProfile` model?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to try `annotate` instead of `aggregate` as below...

```
TopCountries.objects.annotate(Count('top_countries'))
```

Comment: Do you try this?